# Undeclared identifier, out of scope? (Using a C++ list)

Tags: c++

I am trying to access an instance of a list in one of my classes.
However I am getting this error:

> error C2065: 'blocks' : undeclared identifier
>    error C2228: left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union

Here's my code:
    #include

```
class Block{
..
..
};

class Test{
..
..
void doSomething(){
    Block b(70,300,1);
    blocks.push_back(b);
}
};

list<Block> blocks;
Test *test;

int main(){
test->doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code doesn't know what `blocks` is because it is defined globally after the code which is using it.

You need to move this line to be just above the `Test` class:

```
list<Block> blocks;
```

Or alternatively, make this list a member of the `Test` class rather than a global.

Your code has many other issues too.  For example, you have created a pointer to a `Test` object but haven't allocated memory for it.  You need to do this at the start of `main()`:

```
test = new Test();
```

but then you have to delete it too after use:

```
delete test;
```

Even better, just create the `Test` object on the stack in main:

```
Test test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `list<Block> blocks;` is not visible to `doSomething()`. So you can declare the variable before function or, define function after variable.

```
class Test {
...
void doSomething();
};
list<Block> blocks;
...
void Test::doSomething ()
{ ... }
```